# Getting the last element of a split string in Maven archetype properties

Tags: java, arrays, string, maven, maven-archetype

I'm working on a Maven archetype my team will be using. There's a company-wide policy on package naming, so we can assume the Java package will be named like so: `com.company.team.id12345`. That last part, `id12345` is what we're interested in. I want to use that serial number to fill in some values elsewhere in the archetype. The following:

```xml
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="appSerial">
            <defaultValue>${package.split(".")[package.lastIndexOf('.') + 1]}</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>
```

Is what I've tried, but it does not work and defaults to `"package.split(".")[package.lastIndexOf('.') + 1]"` when the `+` is introduced. Any ideas how to fetch the last item of this split string?